# Configurate log4j for external jar

Tags: log4j

In my project (*myProject*) I use an external jar (*external.jar*). Both of them make logging with *log4j.jar* . With the help of *log4j.properties* file (located in myProject) I can configure logging from myProject. How can I configurate log levels of logging from the the *external.jar* without changing that jar file ?

Simpy adding package from *external.jar* ( let say org.external) in property file 
log4j.logger.org.external=ERROR does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[Here I have found the salution.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Q:_Can_I_use_Log4j_with_BIRT.3F)